# Check key presence in Object in ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, associative-array, containskey

How to check if specific key is contained in associative array? I know I can loop over all keys but can I do single-step check?

Comment: `trace("age" in myarray); //will retrun true or false;`

Comment: `if( myarray["age"] != undefined )` will also work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
myObject.hasOwnProperty("field")
```

---

Example Code:

```
var dic:Object = new Object();
dic["field"] = "data";

trace (dic.hasOwnProperty("field")); //true
trace (dic.hasOwnProperty("nofield")); //false
```